# VBA ADO Parameters in loop

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm stuck with one procedure, maybe i'm testing it too long and missing something.
 
Anyway, i have a loop to upload data to database. I wanted to use parameters as data is user input from excel sheet.
 
Three types of data are being uploaded - String, Single, Date 
 
Problem is with single data type values.

```
Dim ProjectList As Variant
Dim Value1 as Long, Value2 as Long
ProjectList = Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(LastRow, "BZ")).Value


   With cmdProject
       .ActiveConnection = cnn
       .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblProject ([Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6], [Field7], " & _
       "[Field8], [Field9], [Field10], [Field11], [Field12], [Field13], [Field14], [Field15], " & _
       "[Field16], [Field17], [Field18], [Field19], [Field20], [Field21], [Field22], [Field23], [Field24], " & _
       "[Field25], [Field26], [Field27], [Field28], [Field29], [Field30], [Field31]) " & _
       "Values ('" & Value1 & "', '" & Value2 & "', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "

       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput)
   End With

   For i = 1 To UBound(ProjectList)
       With cmdProject
          .Parameters.Item(0).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 4))
          .Parameters.Item(1).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 5))
          .Parameters.Item(2).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 6))
          .Parameters.Item(3).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 9))
          .Parameters.Item(4).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 14))
          .Parameters.Item(5).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 17))
          .Parameters.Item(6).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 19))
          .Parameters.Item(7).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 20))
          .Parameters.Item(8).Value = CLng(ProjectList(i, 21))
          .Parameters.Item(9).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 7))
          .Parameters.Item(10).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 8))
          .Parameters.Item(11).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 10))
          .Parameters.Item(12).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 11))
          .Parameters.Item(13).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 12))
          .Parameters.Item(14).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 13))
          .Parameters.Item(15).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 15))
          .Parameters.Item(16).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 16))
          .Parameters.Item(17).Value = CStr(ProjectList(i, 18))
          .Parameters.Item(18).Value = CSng(ProjectList(i, 22))
          .Parameters.Item(19).Value = CSng(ProjectList(i, 23))
          .Parameters.Item(20).Value = CSng(ProjectList(i, 24))
          .Parameters.Item(21).Value = CSng(ProjectList(i, 25))
          .Parameters.Item(22).Value = CSng(ProjectList(i, 29))
          .Parameters.Item(23).Value = CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 30), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
          .Parameters.Item(24).Value = CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 31), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
          .Parameters.Item(25).Value = CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 32), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
          .Parameters.Item(26).Value = CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 33), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
          .Parameters.Item(27).Value = CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 34), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
          .Parameters.Item(28).Value = CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 35), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
          .Execute
       End With
```

I get error on `.execute` 
run time error -2147217913 (80040e07)
Data Type Mismatch In Criteria Expression

Database table has 31 fields (Access accdb) 
Fields 1 to 11 - data type Number - Field Size Long integer 
Fields 12-20 - data type text - field size 255 
Fields 21-25 - data type number - field size Single precision
Fields 26-31 - data type Date/Time 
Single data type values are all set to 1,5

When i omit parameters with single data type values and put some value instead in sql string it's working. 
What's interesting first run of loop uploads data ok so 1 row is always uploaded and it crashes on second. 
 
When I debug and in the second run before `.execute` i go to immediate window and put `cmdProject.Parameters.Item(10).Type = adsingle` it will also upload but again only one row next is with error. 
I can easily run this procedure without using parameters, all data is uploaded in the way i want it. 
 
Also i can upload data like this but i don't want to create new command in each loop

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(ProjectList)
        Set cmdProject = New ADODB.Command
        With cmdProject
           .ActiveConnection = cnn
           .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblProject ([Field1], [Field2], [Field3], [Field4], [Field5], [Field6], [Field7], " & _
           "[Field8], [Field9], [Field10], [Field11], [Field12], [Field13], [Field14], [Field15], " & _
           "[Field16], [Field17], [Field18], [Field19], [Field20], [Field21], [Field22], [Field23], [Field24], " & _
           "[Field25], [Field26], [Field27], [Field28], [Field29], [Field30], [Field31]) " & _
           "Values ('" & Value1 & "', '" & Value2 & "', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 4)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 5)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 6)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 9)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 14)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 17)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 19)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 20)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adBigInt, adParamInput, , CLng(ProjectList(i, 21)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 7)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 8)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 10)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 11)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 12)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 13)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 15)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 16)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adChar, adParamInput, 255, CStr(ProjectList(i, 18)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput, , CSng(ProjectList(i, 22)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput, , CSng(ProjectList(i, 23)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput, , CSng(ProjectList(i, 24)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput, , CSng(ProjectList(i, 25)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adSingle, adParamInput, , CSng(ProjectList(i, 29)))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 30), "YYYY-MM-DD")))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 31), "YYYY-MM-DD")))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 32), "YYYY-MM-DD")))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 33), "YYYY-MM-DD")))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 34), "YYYY-MM-DD")))
           .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adDate, adParamInput, , CDate(Format(ProjectList(i, 35), "YYYY-MM-DD")))
           .execute
       End With
```

It works that way without  problem.
I think it must be something wrong with single data type parameters when assagning value to them but i can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Try to use `adVariant` type for parameter.

Comment: `adVariant` crashes at first loop run unfortunatelly.

Comment: Perhaps, `adDouble`?

Comment: You have a type error, and yet the code you post is skipping parameters, skipping types, and you don't tell us what the data is or looks like. [edit] your question to include the code for all the parameters you're adding, as well as sample parameter values that reproduce the problem, and the actual underlying types of the table you're trying to insert into - see [mcve]. Without an edit, everyone here is stuck taking wild guesses.

Comment: OK Maybe i shortened this too much. I was trying to get possibly shortest description. 
Edit in progress.

Comment: Your post is a bit crazily long and I did not go through the whole thing. With all of what I see, I think you are approaching your problem wrong. With ADO upload, you should just change everything to String and when it lands in database, it will be automatically converted, it just needs to have the right format, for example, if you use "2017/12/25" it will be a string when you read, but when it is stored in the database, if your column is datetime it will read it as date

Comment: That's why i was trying to shorten this, but it was not clear enough when shortened. I can of course use `.Commandtext` without parameters and put data directly into SQL statement. It's easy and working, but this file will be used by different people in more than 10 places all over the world so using parameters gives some protection. There always is possibility that some pissed employee will try to "Drop" employees table. 
It's also working when new command is created each loop. I just want to know why i can't use it when i try to only change parameters values.